# makefile g++: fatal error: no input files

Tags: linux, g++, makefile

I am taking a C++ class right now and in an effort to embrace CS, I installed Linux Mint 15 (Olivia) and have been going through my homework and lectures on the command line and through vim. We recently went over makefile(s) and I am having an issue with g++. My makefile looks like this:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS += -pedantic-errors
CXXFLAGS += -g

OBJS = 

SRCS = constructors.cpp 

HEADERS = 

#target: dependencies
#   rule to build
#

constructors: ${OBJS} ${HEADERS}
    ${CXX} ${LDFLAGS} ${OBJS} -o constructors

${OBJS}: ${SRCS}
    ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} -c $(@:.o=.cpp)
```

When I run:

```
make constructors
```

I get the following message:

```
g++   -o constructors
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [constructors] Error 4
```

I have constructors.cpp in the same folder and if I manually compile it, it works perfect. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> OBJS =
> ```

You... seem to be missing something here. Like some objects to build.

Comment: If I do not have a separate .o file, but I put it in, the compiler still finds it, or creates it? I'm a bit confused on that one. I went ahead and added constructors.o and it compiled, but I'm a bit lost on why. Thank you, by the way!

Comment: The second rule tells `make` how to get stuff in `${OBJS}` from stuff in `${SRCS}`. You may want to look at using `%` though, or even letting the built-in rule for .o files handle it.